# DataSet Compute MAX Value

Tags: c#, dataset

Disclaimer : I am new to C# and WPF and adding features to 
             existing code.

I am facing a problem while calculating the
MAX value of db colums.

I have a Student database with table Sutent_DB

which has StudentID,StudentName,StudentClass
I have to calculate the MAX of SudentID(ie:Number)

That I am doing it from `DataSet.Table[Student_DB].Compute("MAX(StudentID)","")`
Which is returing a Number Object.(Working Fine)

Now I want to restrict my selection to only to selected StudentClass=5

ie : `DataSet.Table[Student_DB].Select("StudentClass=5");`

Here I am facing a problem to calculate the MAX(StudentID) as SELECT returns DATAROW

The solution in my find is

```
  int iMax=0;
  foreach ( DataRow oneNewrow DataSet.Table[Student_DB].Select("StudentClass=5"))
    {
       if iMax < oneNewrow["StudentID"]  

         iMax = oneNewrow["StudentID"]  ;

    }

///use iMax  here.
```

Just want to check any better or simple solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `Compute` is a filter:

```
int maxId = (int)DataSet.Table[Student_DB].Compute("MAX(StudentID)","StudentClass=5");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to Objects on the array of DataRows returned from your query.  Here's an example:

```
int iMax = DataSet.Table[Student_DB].Select("StudentClass=5")).Max(row => row["StudentID"]);
```